# Is it possible to overwrite flag values?

Tags: go

I'm wondering if it's possible to overwrite flag values on runtime.

Example:

- main.go imports a package pkg.go.
- pkg.go uses a flag ("-myFlag") but the identifier which stores the flag is not exported.

Is it possible to change the flag value of "-myFlag" which pkg.go receives from main.go ?

Usecase:  I'm using a library which uses [glog](http://github.com/golang/glog) to log the errors. glog uses flags to define where to write the logs and by default it writes the logs to a file. The environment I'm using doesn't allow writes to filesystem nor to set flags on app initialisation so I need to overwrite/set the glog flags somehow so that I can set it to write the errors to stderr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do [`flag.Set("flagname", "whatever")`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Set).

Or if you want to do something else to the option (check the default, see if it's already been changed, etc) you can use [`f := flag.Lookup("flagname")`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#Lookup) and then `f.Value.Set("whatever")` (as well as other methods).

In either case there are matching `flag.FlagSet` methods if you need this on something other than the `flag.CommandLine` set.

[<kbd>Playground example</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/RvXfJouXQB)

Comment: Also, for flags defined by other packages I like the convention to normally use `flag.Set("flagName", value)`, specifically for `glog`, you probably are looking to do `flag.Set("alsologtostderr", "true")`.

Comment: @user114241very good to point out the simpler function. D'oh! I was snarky in my reference/link to the documentation but then failed to pick the easiest documented option! Note to self: Must more fully re-read *complete* documentation before answering questions!